# SkiaSharp resizing image - high memory usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, image-manipulation, skiasharp

We are using .NET 7 web MVC application and SkiaSharp 2.88.5. We have `LoadImage` controller action which receives `imageId` and `scaleFactor` parameters and scales the image according to the scaling factor. The image can be either in JPG or PNG format.

```cs
public IActionResult LoadImage(int imageId, double scaleFactor)
{
    var path = _imageService.GetImagePath(imageId);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
        var contentType = FileTypeMapping.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        var img = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);

        var resizedImage = FileHelpers.ResizeImage(img, extension, scaleFactor);
        return File(resizedImage, contentType);
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

The following method performs resizing operation using SkiaSharp library:

```cs
private static readonly Dictionary<string, SKEncodedImageFormat> _skiaSharpImageFormatMapping = new(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    {".png", SKEncodedImageFormat.Png },
    {".jpg", SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg },
    {".jpeg", SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg },
    {".jpe", SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg },
};

public static Stream ResizeImage(Stream imgStream, string extension, double scaleFactor)
{
    using (var skData = SKData.Create(imgStream))
    {
        using (var skImage = SKBitmap.Decode(skData))
        {
            int newHeight = (int)(skImage.Height * scaleFactor);
            int newWidth = (int)(skImage.Width * scaleFactor);

            using (var scaledBitmap = skImage.Resize(new SKImageInfo(newWidth, newHeight), SKFilterQuality.Low))
            {
                using (var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(scaledBitmap))
                {
                    using (var encodedImage = image.Encode(_skiaSharpImageFormatMapping[extension], 50))
                    {
                        var stream = new MemoryStream();
                        encodedImage.SaveTo(stream);
                        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        return stream;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The image that we are trying to resize is a JPG image of size 2963KB (4032x3025px). When we call `/LoadImage?imageId=555&scaleFactor=0.5` endpoint, we can observe the following increase in process memory:

[image]

The memory increased from 385MB to 471MB, which is an increase of **86MB**. The increase seems quite high, especially considering the fact that the image is only 2.9MB in size. It becomes problematic when multiple clients call `LoadImage` action at the same time. The server can quickly run out of memory.

Is such memory increase expected? How can we make it more memory-efficient? Is there something wrong with the resizing algorithm (`ResizeImage` method) that we use which causes before-mentioned problem?

Comment: Well, you could play around with different settings, but honestly: I am not surprised. Resizing a jpeg, you need to decode it, run your resizing / resampling algorithms on it and reencode it. All in all very memory-hungry procedures. Avoiding memory problems outside of the resizing itself could include: "sequentialize requests", so only one image is resized at a time, "Caching" - don't resize the same image twice to the same new size, ...

Comment: You are also nesting all the usings, when you actually do not need to hold on to everything throughout the whole process. You _could_ dispose earlier.